# Alternative way to fetch url data

Tags: php, html

Let’s say my url is mywebsite.com/login?code=xxxxxxxxxx..

I have used isset($_GET[‘code’]) method to retrieve the data.

I’d like to know any other ways to fetch the url data(value of code)

Comment: Why would you need another way? What's wrong with the current approach? But no, I don't know of a better one I don't think

Comment: That already is the most common and most convenient method. You _could_ also fish the full query string content out of $_SERVER and then parse it yourself, but ... why.

Comment: @CBroe Maybe just for learning purpose sometimes deep knowledge are required to optimize something or just to know what we should avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP have few functions to work around url parameters but $_GET is most common and easiest to work around / read

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

```
$code = isset($_REQUEST['code']) ? $_REQUEST['code'] : '';
```

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

```
$code = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'code');
```

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$actual_link = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$query = parse_url($actual_link, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $params);
$code = isset($params['code']) ? $params['code'] : '';
```